# Atributo timezone_type da classe DateTime

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber quais são os tipos de valores que o atributo `timezone_type` pode receber. Pelo que entendi ele pode receber os números **1**, **2** e **3**. Mas qual é a diferença entre cada um desses valores que o atributo `timezone_type` pode receber.

```
 object(DateTime)[3]
      public 'date' => string '2020-09-30 14:32:03.661324' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'America/Sao_Paulo' (length=17)
```

Comment: relacionada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694894/different-timezone-types-on-datetime-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os três tipos diferentes de objetos DateTime:

**Tipo 1 - UTC offset**

A compensação UTC é a diferença em horas e minutos do Tempo Universal Coordenado (UTC) para um determinado local e data.

`new DateTime("17 July 2013 -0300");`

**Tipo 2 - timezone abbreviation**

Tempo Médio de Greenwich (TMG) ou Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) em inglês, também conhecido por Hora de Greenwich, é a média do horário solar aparente no Observatório Real, em Greenwich, Londres.

`new DateTime("17 July 2013 GMT");`

**Tipo 3 - timezone identifier** Que é a saída do seu *var_dump()*, no corpo da questão, é do tipo 3. O identificador do fuso horário, como UTC ou America/Sao_Paulo. A lista de identificadores válidos está disponível na documentação do php.net. [Lista de Fusos Horários Suportados](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php)

`new DateTime( "17 July 2013", new DateTimeZone("Europe/London"));`

*Mais sobre a questão em língua inglesa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694894/different-timezone-types-on-datetime-object*